# How does the find_package NAMES option work?

Tags: qt, cmake

The following code is from QtCreator's project templates:

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_MAJOR_VERSION} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
```

From the documents: <sub>[find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)</sub>

> If the NAMES option is given, the names following it are used instead of `<PackageName>`. The names are also considered when determining whether to redirect the call to a package provided by FetchContent.

And from the source code: [Source/cmFindPackageCommand.cxx#L1081-1096](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmFindPackageCommand.cxx?ref_type=heads#L1081-1096):

```cpp
const auto redirectsDir =
    this->Makefile->GetSafeDefinition("CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_REDIRECTS_DIR");
for (const auto& overrideName : overrideNames) {
  const auto nameLower = cmSystemTools::LowerCase(overrideName);
  if (cmSystemTools::FileExists(
        cmStrCat(redirectsDir, '/', nameLower, "-config.cmake")) ||
      cmSystemTools::FileExists(
        cmStrCat(redirectsDir, '/', overrideName, "Config.cmake"))) {
    // Force the use of this redirected config package file, regardless of
    // the type of find_package() call. Files in the redirectsDir must always
    // take priority over everything else.
    forceConfigMode = true;
    this->UseConfigFiles = true;
    this->UseFindModules = false;
    this->Names.clear();
    this->Names.emplace_back(overrideName); // Force finding this one
    this->Variable = cmStrCat(this->Name, "_DIR");
    this->SetConfigDirCacheVariable(redirectsDir);
    break;
  }
}
```

And from the CMake output(with `CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE` set to `TRUE`):

```bash
  The file was found at
    /usr/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake
```

It seems that NAMES should help to find those config files. But it will make some changes to variables that I can't understand:

```
find_package(ghasem NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${ghasem_MAJOR_VERSION} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
```

I can't understand where was `ghasem_MAJOR_VERSION` created and how that is work.

Comment: Not sure about `ghasem_MAJOR_VERSION`; that may be logic in the qt configuration scripts. `ghasem_VERSION_MAJOR` should be set, by cmake, see [the Config Mode Version Selection of the cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#package-file-interface-variables). In this case the `NAMES` values cause cmake to look for `Qt6Config.cmake` and `Qt5Config.cmake` when searching for package configuration files.

Comment: Anyways you don't need to use `find_package` twice in your project; simply use `target_link_libraries(... Qt::Core)`, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-qt5-and-qt6-compatibility.html#versionless-targets

Comment: I want to know how NAMES work and where `ghasem_MAJOR_VERSION` was set. I also checked the Qt configuration scripts and couldn't find a clue.

Comment: Those variables that are mentioned in the Config Mode Version ... are different from what is set by using NAMES options